# Web Audio API - Automatic Gain Control?

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, volume

Is there a way to create automatic gain control with the web-audio api? In my case, I'm building a web-based video chat app that takes multiple audio streams (people talking) and plays them. Is there a way to adjust their relative volume-levels such that everyone has roughly the same loudness? I don't want one person to sound very quiet while another person sounds very loud.

GainNodes appear to be very manually; they expect you to figure out what the .gain.value should be. I suppose I could run every audio track through an analyserNode, compute a volume level, and then manually adjust each person's individual gain-node based on that, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do automatic gain control? Thanks.

Comment: Implementing a peak meter with AnalyserNodes would be simple solution, as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're making a web-based chat app, automatic gain control is actually easily handled when you capture microphone audio in the first place:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    autoGainControl: true
  },
  video: true
});
```

(Note that `autoGainControl` is actually on by default.  You don't need to manually enable it.)

However, if you still want to reduce the dynamics range on playback, what you're looking for is a [DynamicsCompressorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DynamicsCompressorNode).  This will squash variances between the loud and quiet parts.  After that node, you can add a fixed GainNode to make up for the losses in the compressor.

The [specific compression settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DynamicsCompressorNode/DynamicsCompressorNode) you use are a matter of taste, and there is a great deal of debate on this.  You might start with a 2ms attack time, 10ms release time, 3:1 ratio, -20 dB threshold, and perhaps 6 dB of makeup gain, and tweak from there.

Comment: I think it's very useful to point out the existence of the `autoGainControl` setting and that may be sufficient to address @paul-fidika 's concern in practice, but I think he's asking slightly different question. autoGainControl is going to operate on the level of an individual input source (mic), by definition. I think the issue Paul is trying to address is the possibility that different input streams may have different volume levels. I suspect there's nothing in the base WebAudio API for this, but it wouldn't be hard to manually measure the input level and adjust the gain accordingly.

Comment: Yes exactly. I haven't tried using a DynamicsCompressorNode yet, but I can give that one a shot. I think what I'm going to do is connect each participant's audio-input to an AnalyserNode and GainNode, calculate their relative volume levels, and then use that to adjust the .gain property on the GainNode. That way one person isn't significantly louder than another.

Comment: The dynamics compressor, will do the exact same thing without effort on your part.  :-)